# why is my character bliting two different images at the same time

Tags: python, image, file-upload, pygame, pygame-surface

im making a game and a the character is ment to show a gun animation depending on what position he was facing
here is the code the determines that

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.velo = 8
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.Idlecount = 0
        self.guncount = 0
        self.gunisfired = False
        self.isIdle = False
        self.standing = True

    def draw(self, screen):
        #draws all the animations to the screen
        if self.walkcount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkcount = 0
        elif self.Idlecount + 1 >= 27:
            self.Idlecount = 0
        if not(self.standing):
            if self.left:
                screen.blit(walkLeft[self.walkcount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
                if self.gunisfired == True:
                    if self.guncount//5 >= len(ShootR):
                        self.guncount = 0
                        self.gunisfired == False
                    screen.blit(ShootR[self.guncount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.guncount += 1

            if self.right:
                screen.blit(walkRight[self.walkcount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
                if self.gunisfired == True:
                    if self.guncount//5 >= len(ShootR):
                        self.guncount = 0
                        self.gunisfired == False
                    screen.blit(ShootR[self.guncount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.guncount += 1
        else:
            if self.left:
                if self.isIdle == True:
                    if self.Idlecount//3 >= len(IdleL):
                        self.Idlecount = 0
                        self.isIdle == False
                    screen.blit(IdleL[self.Idlecount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.Idlecount += 1
                if self.gunisfired == True:
                    if self.guncount//5 >= len(ShootL):
                        self.guncount = 0
                        self.gunisfired == False
                    screen.blit(ShootL[self.guncount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.guncount += 1
            else:
                if self.Idlecount//3 >= len(IdleR):
                    self.Idlecount = 0
                    self.isIdle == False
                screen.blit(IdleR[self.Idlecount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Idlecount += 1
                if self.gunisfired == True:
                    if self.guncount//5 >= len(ShootR):
                        self.guncount = 0
                        self.gunisfired == False
                    screen.blit(ShootR[self.guncount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.guncount += 1

        pygame.display.update()
```

and here is the code for the keyboard bindings

```
man = Player(300, 508, 64, 64)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.velo:
        man.x -= man.velo
        man.right = False
        man.left = True
        man.Idlecount = 0
        man.guncount = 0
        man.gunisfired = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 600 - man.width - man.velo:
        man.x += man.velo
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.Idlecount = 0
        man.guncount = 0
        man.gunisfired = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        man.gunisfired = True
        man.isIdle = False
        man.standing = True
        man.Idlecount = 0
    else:
        man.walkcount = 0
        man.isIdle = True
        man.guncount = 0
        man.gunisfired = False
        man.standing = True
```

The ting is that the gun image is working when he is facing left but when it is right it seems to blit it with the forst image of the idle animation. can someone please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if self.isIdle == True` is missing in the else case of the method `draw`:

```py
class Player(object):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, screen):
        # [...]

        if not(self.standing):
            # [...]

        else:
            if self.left:
               # [...]

            else:

                if self.isIdle == True:  # <---- this is missing
                    if self.Idlecount//3 >= len(IdleR):
                        self.Idlecount = 0
                        self.isIdle == False
                    screen.blit(IdleR[self.Idlecount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.Idlecount += 1
                if self.gunisfired == True:
                    if self.guncount//5 >= len(ShootR):
                        self.guncount = 0
                        self.gunisfired == False
                    screen.blit(ShootR[self.guncount//5], (self.x,self.y))
                    self.guncount += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for what you said i applied it and it worked